# Catched except in django transaction.atomic() block rollbacks transaction

Tags: python, django, pytest

I have a block of code like this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    for i in some_objects:
        stop_object(i)
    for i in some_objects:
        try:
           activate_object(i)
        except IntegrityError as e:
           pass
```

Test is written with py.test. For some reason, when I catch IntegrityError all transaction is rolling back and I have the exact same state as before.

I was sure transaction should rollback only on errors I don't catch. Am I missing something?

Not sure also how I can debug it. If you have some ideas, please share them.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out needed to add another transaction.atomic() block:

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    for i in some_objects:
        stop_object(i)
    for i in some_objects:
        try:
           with transaction.atomic():
               activate_object(i)
        except IntegrityError as e:
           pass
```